# angular ng-repeat no access to controller or Unique how to depdue?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following select but I dont have access to the controller or to unique. Is there any way to dedupe the items ?

```
<select ng-model="searchTerm  " size="20" >
    <option value=null>Default</option>
    <option ng-repeat="g in model.availableItems | orderby :'config.group'" value="{{g.config.group}}">{{g.config.group}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Please post your working example. And your sample data of model.availableItems.

Answer (score 0):

Declare "availableItems" as variable in controller and use like this:

```
g in availableItems
```

and not

```
g in model.availableItems
```

Full Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.searchTerm = "";
      $scope.availableItems = [
        {
          name: '1',
          config: {
              group: '2'
          }
        },
        {
          name: '4',
          config: {
              group: '3'
          }
        },
        {
          name: '5',
          config: {
              group: '1'
          }
        }
      ];
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select ng-model="searchTerm" size="20" >
    <option value=null>Default</option>
    <option ng-repeat="g in availableItems | orderBy:'config.group'" value="{{g.config.group}}">{{g.config.group}}</option>
  </select>

  <p>Selected item is: {{searchTerm}}</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```